# gutenburg run js function on post save

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

What I would like to happen:

1. user presses save-draft or publish
2. function is ran

However, I cannot figure out how to hook into post save function from the front-end of gutenburg.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure this out. For anybody curious, I followed this tutorial:

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/javascript/js-build-setup/#utm_medium=referral&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_content=social

And then used this code:

```
import { select, subscribe } from '@wordpress/data';
const { isSavingPost } = select( 'core/editor' );

console.log("hola amigo")

var checked = true;

subscribe( () => {
  if ( isSavingPost() ) {
    checked = false;
  } else {
    if ( ! checked ) {
      console.log("Tasty burritos")
      checked = true;
    }
  }
} );
```